# Return Enum String based on Enum Name

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following code which does not work but you can get an idea of what I am trying to do. I am not sure how to get a string based on the Enum. I am passing the Enum Name to the Method:

```
   class StateInfo
    {
        enum State{ Illinois= 0, Ohio= 1, Indiana= 2, Michigan= 3, Conneticut= 4 }; 

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            string result = ConvToJson("State");

        }


        public static string ConvToJson(string enumName)
        {

           Type e = Enum.GetName(typeof(enumName));

          var ret = "{";

          foreach (var val in Enum.GetValues(e))
          {
             var name = Enum.GetName(e, val);
            ret += name + ":" + ((int)val).ToString() + ",";
          }

        ret += "}";

        return ret;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Type.GetType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) to get the [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) from a string specifying the type's name:

```
Type e = Type.GetType(enumName);
```

The name must specify the full namespace and, if the type is not in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, also the assembly name:

```
string result = ConvToJson("MyNamespace.StateInfo+State");
string result = ConvToJson("MyNamespace.StateInfo+State, MyAssembly, " +
    "Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b17a5c561934e089");
```

---

It might be easier to pass the type directly to the method:

```
string result = ConvToJson(typeof(State));
```

```
public static string ConvToJson(Type e)
```

Comment: Hello, based on string result = ConvToJson("MyNamespace.State"); I have a situation where  Type e = Type.GetType(enumName); is null though. I substituted MyNamespace with a valid namespace.